# While loop - JAVA

Tags: java, while-loop

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    double startingMile;
    System.out.print("Enter the starting mile: ");
    startingMile = input.nextDouble();
    double endingMile;
    System.out.print("Enter the ending mile: ");
    endingMile = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("");

    double countOne;
    countOne = startingMile;
    while (countOne <= endingMile) {
        endingMile = countOne * 1.609;
        System.out.println("miles: " + countOne + "," + " Kilometers: " + endingMile);
        countOne++;
    }
```

This is what my output should look like but it keeps giving me infinite loop for output. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

```
 Enter the starting mile: 2
 Enter the ending mile: 4

 miles: 2, kilometers: 3.218
 miles: 3, kilometers: 4.827
 miles: 4, kilometers: 6.436
```

Comment: Think what you're doing in the loop, man. You're increasing **both** endingMile and countOne in a way such that the while condition will **never** be false.

Comment: @Hovercraft nvm not speaking my words right lol and that too^

Comment: the chance of it to stop is 0% :) your endingMile has a multiplier of 1.609 while your countOne has an increment of 1 only

Comment: shouldn't it be `while (startingMile <= endingMile) {...}` ?

Comment: it actually depends on what  he want to achieve.

Comment: @ochi: how will that help if he doesn't change startingMile within the loop?

Comment: @ochi . no. it will always return false

Comment: @jace my take is that OP wants to display the entered starting mile and its conversion to KMs until the entered ending mile, one by one in a loop (if I am reading the desired output correctly)

Comment: @jace sure, of course, along with incrementing the starting mile along the way- I was trying to throw hints

Comment: what you're actually trying to say is , if startingMile is less than or equal to endingMile. but startingmile will never be greater than endingMile, except you do the moonwalk :D :'(

Comment: i do now get it ochi :) thanks to your comment i realized it

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thank you... yes, it was obviously not accurate but hinting at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is actually what you want to achieve.

While leaping of +1 from starting mile till you reach the ending miles, you always want to convert your mile to km :) thanks to @Ochi for his comment, I realized it by that although it is not a direct statement :D. Still sharing the credit :).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

double startingMile;
System.out.print("Enter the starting mile: ");
startingMile = input.nextDouble();
double endingMile;
System.out.print("Enter the ending mile: ");
endingMile = input.nextDouble();
System.out.println("");

double convertedKM;
while (startingMile <= endingMile) {
    convertedKM = startingMile * 1.609;
    System.out.println("miles: " + startingMile + "," + " Kilometers: " + convertedKM);
    startingMile++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the credits, glad you got the points (your answer, your points ;) )

Comment: so what would I have to do if it was do-while loop?

Comment: output from do while and while will still be the same so there is no problem with that. except in do-while, your program will do the work first before the comparison of while :) In while statement, comparison first before "do this work"

Comment: I'm doing do-while rn and it's not resetting to input value of startingMile it just stops at 5.0, but it's supposed to be doing 2.0 - 4.0 just like while loop

Comment: do {
            convertedKM = startingMile * 1.609;
            System.out.println("miles: " + startingMile + "," + " Kilometers: " + convertedKM);
            startingMile++;
            
        } while (startingMile <= endingMile);

Answer (score 0):

The condition in a `while` loop is evaluated each time you go through the loop, *using the current values of all variables*.  You may have thought that this

```
while (countOne <= endingMile) {
```

would look at `endingMile`'s value before the first iteration, and use that as the loop's upper bound.  But instead, it looks at the value of `endingMile` every time.  So if you change `endingMile` inside the loop, as you're doing, the comparison will be done using the new value, every time.

To fix this, set up another variable, so that `endingMile` won't need to change.